# Azure Event Hub - EventProcessor.Process is too slow

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am running a background service in azure web app for processing events from Azure Event Hub. I have created an ASP.NET core SignalR web app. I am getting some "unknown errors" when the server response time is high. This usually happens when multiple clients connect/disconnect. I did further debugging and found that "EventProcessor.Process" is taking too long to respond and thus interrupting with the volume of processed messages. Below is the screenshot from app insights: -

[image]

Below is my code responsible for event processing and checkpointing: -

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(_storageConnectionString, _blobContainerName);
    await storageClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    var processor = new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, _consumerGroup, _eventHubConnectionString, _eventHubName);

    Task processErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    try
    {
        processor.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEvent;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += processErrorHandler;

        try
        {

            await processor.StartProcessingAsync(stoppingToken);
            await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        processor.ProcessEventAsync -= ProcessEvent;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync -= processErrorHandler;
    }
}

private static Dictionary<string, int> _eventCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private async Task ProcessEvent(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    MessageData messageData = GetEventData(eventArgs.Data);
    if (messageData != null)
    {
        var messageConfig = businessMessages.FirstOrDefault(bm => bm.MessageId == messageData.MessageId);
        var viewModel = new MessageViewModel(messageData);
        var messageId = messageData.MessageId;
        var fullMessageGroup = $"full-{messageId}";
        var fullMessageUpdate = new UpdateViewModel<MessageDataViewModel>()
        {
            MessageId = messageConfig.MessageNumber,
            Data = viewModel,
            Category = "Full"
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fullMessageUpdate);
        await _hubContext.Clients.Group(fullMessageGroup).SendCoreAsync("MessageUpdate", new object[] { fullMessageUpdate });
    }

    if (!_eventCount.ContainsKey(eventArgs.Partition.PartitionId))
    {
        _eventCount[eventArgs.Partition.PartitionId] = 0;
    }
    if (_eventCount[eventArgs.Partition.PartitionId]++ == 100)
    {
        _eventCount[eventArgs.Partition.PartitionId] = 0;
        await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync(eventArgs.CancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I think that something is wrong with the event hub checkpointing. It would be great if someone helps me here. I have been stuck here for past 2 days. FYI, normal message volume should be 1 million per hour if no client is connected.

Comment: Have you identified what part of `ProcessEvent` takes most of the time?

Comment: I'd recommend changing your `_eventCount` store to a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>`.    Your `ProcessEvent` handler will be invoked concurrently and the standard dictionary that you're using is not thread-safe.   It's possible that is throwing off your calculations and impacting checkpointing.

Comment: In addition to Peter's question, I'd like to understand how many partitions your Event Hub has, how many processor instances are in use, and how many cores the host machines have.   At the rate of 1 million events per hour, you're looking at roughly 278 events per second.   Ensuring the work is distributed to allow a reasonable amount of concurrency and that you're not experiencing contention in the thread pool are going to be key for maintaining consistent throughput.

Comment: @PeterBons I have few logics in ProcessEvent which could potentially increase execution time but the execution time should always be high in that case. Once all the clients are connected, everything is running smoothly (Avg 400 ms per execution). The problem happens when multiple clients connect/disconnect at the same time.

Comment: @JesseSquire I will try your suggestion. I have 32 partitions, 3 processor instances are running and using App service plan (P2V2).

Comment: The P2V2 plan has 2 cores;  you're asking each processor client to handle between 10 and 11 partitions - each of which runs as a dedicated background task.   The processor itself also has a persistent management background task running and is highly asynchronous in its operation.     You've very likely seeing contention in the thread pool that is causing delays scheduling continuations - including for the async calls in your handler.   With 2 cores, I'd recommend having your processor responsible for no more than 4-6 partitions;  I'd test with 4 before increasing.

Comment: @JesseSquire Thanks ! I am going to try this now.

Comment: Is there any update on this question .